# DataBound DropDownList in DataGrid - order of binding

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, datagrid, webforms, drop-down-menu

I have a DataGrid that looks like this (slightly simplified here):

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="grdQuotas" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="quotas-header" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateColumn>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                Max order level</HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMaxOrderLevel" runat="server" DataSourceID="xdsOrderLevel"
                    DataTextField="Text" DataValueField="Value" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("MaxOrderLevel") %>'>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateColumn>
    </Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>

<asp:XmlDataSource ID="xdsOrderLevel" runat="server" DataFile="~/App_Data/OrderLevels.xml">
</asp:XmlDataSource>
```

In my `Page_Load` event handler I am creating a `DataTable` containing default values and `DataBind`ing it to the `DataGrid`.

The problem is that this is taking place *before* the `DropDownList` **ddlMaxOrderLevel** has been bound to its `DataSource`, so I get a runtime error telling me that the `SelectedValue` cannot be set.

If **ddlMaxOrderLevel** was not in a `DataGrid` I could just call `DataBind()` on it. However I cannot do that in this scenario - since it is in an `ItemTemplate`.

Can anyone suggest a workaround or alternate approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create another DataSource and bind it to the DataGrid.  Where the SelectMethod would return the default values in a simple object.

Then all the binding should happily work together.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the Databinding of the DropDownlist in the Databound event of the DataGrid.

Edit:
I will give you an example that i have tested:

```
 protected void dg_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.Header && e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.Footer)
        {
            DropDownList dl = (DropDownList)((DataGridItem)e.Item).FindControl("ddlMaxOrderLevel");

            dl.DataSource = levels;
            dl.DataBind();

            dl.SelectedValue = ((DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem)["number"].ToString();


        }

    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work for the same reason as outlined in my original question: The DropDownList is within an ItemTemplate, so does not exist as an instantiated control that you can reference

Comment: But you can use DataGridItem.FindControl to find the DDL by ID and DataGridItem.DataItem to get the "MaxOrderLevel." Then you can set the list's selected value with the same property that you've currently got in the markup.

Comment: Plz tell me if this helped you or if you haved found a better answer